# Have a parent's page title tag be used as the title tag for all children

Tags: javascript, html, .net, razor

I'm working on a large website project and we have a default layout, which contains a `<title> My Title </title>` tag that is used on all other pages.

How can I keep that title until I get to a specific page where I would like it to change to `<title> Other Title - My Title </title>` for the current page and all children of that page without having to edit each child page manually?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

I have a layout page that I want to override for a certain subset of pages (which are all children of a particular page)

Comment: What framework are you using to build your site? I see that you are using `razor` for compiling views, but it would help to have a little bit more information about your site architecture as it would help to tell you where the metadata should go that will allow you to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.5.1

Comment: Why don't you use the ViewBag. For example, say the child page is child.cshtml, use `ViewBag.SpecialTitle = "I am the awesome child"`, read the `ViewBag` in the master and display it if it is not null

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done anything in `razor` but this might work. In your main layout file, e.g. `Index.cshtml` you could add a `@helper` to streamline the formatting, e.g.:

```
@helper formatTitle(string subtitle) {
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subtitle)) {
        @:<title>subtitle - My Title</title>
    } else {
        @:<title>My Title</title>
    }
}

<html>
    <head>
        @formatTitle(Model.Subtitle)
    ...
    </head>
...
</html>
```

Then just make sure you set the `Model.Subtitle` value for each page where you want the subtitle to display in front of the site title.

Comment: That didn't work :-(. It kept the same title as before

Comment: So if it is not throwing any errors, either `Model.subtitle` is not set or there may be a syntax error in the helper function that means that `subtitle` is not output. It's also possible that your previous template was cached and so you're not seeing the changes.

Comment: On the layout file, I do not have access to the model. To add that would I just add `@model myModel` to the top of the page?